# JQuery Shuffle Effect using Html5 [Canvas +CSS +JS]

Tags: jquery, animation, html, canvas, drawing

I saw a JQuery Shuffle [Example](http://hungred.com/wp-content/demo/jQuery-Shuffle-effect/demo.html)  and
I was trying to implement the same using HTML5 and Canvas + CSS + JS with images.

but finding animation/drawing using Canvas bit difficult.

I just had idea of creating as many canvas as images and then try to move the canvas
for shuffle animation.

Are there any libraries to achieve the same.

Anyone can help me with the same.

**Edit:

Here is how i got the effect using Jquery  ..(few bugs thr)
i have achieved the effect using Jquery and some 
libraries..but it is basically thr manipulating CSS values...

i was trying to do something with just canvas based drawing apis.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

<style type="text/css">
canvas
{ 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px; 
 width: 800px;
 height:600px;
}
.easing_example {
border:1px solid #777777;
padding:0.5em;
position:relative;
width:4em;
}
 img {display:none;}
.landscape #ps_container{ width: 1000px; height: 600px; }

#ecard-wrapper{ margin: 20px auto; width: 980px; }
#ps_container{ border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;  margin: 25px 20px 0 0; overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: left; }


</style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery-css-transform.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>





    <script type="text/javascript">
    var viewport = { obj: null, width: 0, height: 0 };
    var timerId=null;
    var timeInterval=10;
    var factor=5;
    var topZIndex=0;


    var currentCanvasCount=0;

    function  CVImage()
    {
         this.ImageSource = null;//string
         this.size ={ x: 0, y: 0 };
         this.position = {x: 0, y: 0};
         this.Rotate = 0;
         this.Canvas = null;
         this.Context = null;
         this.Image =null;
    }


    CVImage.prototype.draw = function()
    {
        var img = new Image();               
        img.src = this.ImageSource;
        this.Image=img;
        var context = this.Context;
        context.drawImage(img,this.position.x - this.size.x /2,this.position.y - this.size.y /2, 
        this.size.x, this.size.y);                
    }

    CVImage.prototype.update =function(){
        var context = this.Context;
        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0,0, this.Canvas.width, this.Canvas.height);
        context.translate(this.size.x/2,this.size.y/2);
        context.rotate(this.Rotate * Math.PI/180);
        this.draw();
        context.restore();
    }

    CVImage.prototype.slideOut =function(){
        var context = this.Context;
        var canvas = this.Canvas;
        $(canvas)
                .animate(
                            {left: 10,top: -20}, 
                    {
                            duration: 700,
                            easing: 'easeOutBack'
                    })
                .animate(
                            {rotate: '20deg',top:-250,left:375},
                    {
                            duration: 1000,
                            easing: 'easeOutBack',
                            complete : function(){topZIndex--;$(this).css("z-index", topZIndex);}

                    })
                .animate(
                            {top:0,left: 0,rotate: '0deg'}, 
                    {
                            duration: 1000,
                            easing: 'easeOutBack',
                            complete:continueAnimation 
                    });

    }


     function continueAnimation()
        {       
          if( currentCanvasCount >0)
          {
            var canvasObj = CanvasArr[currentCanvasCount-1];
            if(canvasObj!=null)
            {
             canvasObj.slideOut();
             currentCanvasCount--;
            }
          }
          else if(currentCanvasCount == 0)
          {
           startShuffle();
          }

        }   

        $(document).ready(function() {
        init();     

                $("#start_flip").click( function(){ 
                          startShuffle();

                });     
        });


        var CanvasArr = new Array();        
        function startShuffle(){
             var i =0;
             currentCanvasCount=CanvasArr.length;
             continueAnimation();
        }


        function init() 
        {

            var i = 0;          
            viewport.obj = $('#ps_container');
            viewport.width = viewport.obj[0].clientWidth;
            viewport.height = viewport.obj[0].clientHeight;

            var images = $(".images_collection img");
            for (i = 0; i < images.length ; i++)  
            {
                var cid = "canvas_" + ""+i;
                var canvas = document.getElementById(cid);
                canvas.width = viewport.width;
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var cvimg = new CVImage();
                cvimg.ImageSource = images[i].src;
                cvimg.size.x = parseInt(images[i].width);
                cvimg.size.y = parseInt(images[i].height);
                cvimg.position.x = 350;
                cvimg.position.y = 250;
                cvimg.Canvas = canvas;          
                cvimg.Context = ctx;        
                CanvasArr.push(cvimg);
            }
            DrawCanvas();           
            //timerId = setInterval(DrawCanvas,timeInterval);
        }

        function DrawCanvas()
        {
        var i =0;
        var canv =null;
        for(i=0;i<CanvasArr.length;i++)
          {
            canv = CanvasArr[i];
            canv.update();
          }
        }       



    </script>

</head>
<body>


      <a href="#" id="start_flip">START SHUFFLE</a>

      <a href="#" id="stop_flip">STOPP SHUFFLE</a>

      <div class="easing_example" id="easing_example_3" style="left: 0px;">Click Me</div>

     <div id="images_collection" class="images_collection" style="display: none">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/Chichen Itza.jpg" alt="" /></a> <a href="#">
                <img src="images/Great Wall of China.jpg" alt="" /></a> <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/Machu Picchu.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <div id="ecard-wrapper" class="landscape">
    <div id="ps_container" style="display: block; position: fixed; top: 150px; left: 80px">
        <canvas id="canvas_0" height="800" width="600" ></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas_1" height="800" width="600" ></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas_2" height="800" width="600" ></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas_3" height="800" width="600" ></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks All.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to re-implement? If you're looking for libraries to achieve this effect, why not just use the JQuery implementation you link to?

Comment: well i have achieved the effect using Jquery and some libraries..
but it is basically thr manipulating CSS values...
i was trying to do something with just canvas based drawing apis.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be making a canvas for each image, then it would not be different from the CSS approach, making it redundant. But if you're going to draw it on a very big canvas, and if you understand about z-index and animation, this is not all too hard to achieve. Read up [this primer on canvas animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations).

The steps would be:

1. Prepare all images to be drawn using `new Image` object and setting its `src`.
2. At most you would be drawing is two images at a time. Say in the beginning, you have image 1 in front of image 2. Draw image 2 first, then draw image 1 on top of it. (In the first frame, maybe you need to only draw image 1)
3. Animate image 1 to move it further away from image 2, with drawing order the same as step 2.
4. Once it is far enough, change the drawing order, so that image 1 is drawn first, then image 2. Animate image 1 to move it closer to image 2, until it goes under it.
5. Once image 1 is under image 2, you can swap it with image 3 and repeat.

Comment: "At most you would be drawing is two images at a time."  - not true, try clicking on the square in the example page several times in quick succession.

Comment: If you understand the mechanism, it is quite trivial to implement more than two images. You just need to add more layers.